# Android PdfRenderer throws IOException

Tags: android, pdf, ioexception, pdfrenderer, pdf-rendering

My application lists PDF files, and when the user selects a PDF, the app opens it. If the **user selects a corrupted PDF file, PdfRenderer throws `IOException`** (which is fine, since I catch that exception and inform the user that the file is corrupted).

But the issue is, after this happens, **`IOException` is thrown for all the PDF files the user is trying to open (Even for the non-corrupted ones)**

**Relevant code**

```
File file = new File(filePath);
mFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
if (mFileDescriptor != null) {
     mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(mFileDescriptor);
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
openRenderer: java.io.IOException: file not in PDF format or corrupted
    at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.<init>(PdfRenderer.java:166)
    at ****.****.****.PdfUtil.openRenderer(PdfUtil.java:63)
    at ****.****.****.PdfUtil.getMaxPages(PdfUtil.java:46)
    at ****.****.****.PdfViewActivity.init(PdfViewActivity.java:166)
    at ****.****.****.ui.PdfViewActivity.onCreate(PdfViewActivity.java:58)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

NB : I have already tried copying pdf file to cache directory. It doesn't make a difference.

Same issue in PdfRenderer google sample repo [here.](https://github.com/android/graphics-samples/issues/23)

Comment: Just commenting that I’m running into the exact same issue. It also appears we’re not the only ones running into this issue. I found this issue (but closed). I may attempt to add my own project and re-file this bug with my own project

Comment: @codecaffeine This [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37052344) says it's been fixed in Android P.

Comment: Did you find any solution ? If yes, please share the answer.

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy Unfortunately, no. The bug is still there.